# Automate to subscribe a YouTube video

Tags: python, selenium, youtube, webdriver

I am a python coder learning Selenium webdriver. I was able to perform like on any YouTube video by using **XPATH** but I couldn't figure out the way to subscribe the same video owner's channel through selenium.
Check out my code below and please suggest some ways to correct this and if this is correct then please suggest the current method for `find_element_by_` to detect/find subscribe button.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from chromedriver_py import binary_path

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=binary_path)
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7G72oJyfhKk')

time.sleep(2)

#for like button (works fine):
like_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="info"]//ytd-toggle-button-renderer[1]//a[1]//yt-icon-button[1]//button[1]//yt-icon[1]')
like_btn.click()

#for subscribe button (didn't work):
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 300)") #scrolling down 300px to make subscribe button visible
subs_btn = driver.find_element_by_class_xpath('//*[@id="button"]')
subs_btn.click()
```

On running above code it works fine up to like button then it raises the following error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Answer (score 0):

For subscribe button try to use following code with relative xpath

```
subscribe_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//yt-formatted-string[contains(text(),'Subscribe')]')
subscribe_btn.click()
```

Please be aware that this solution will work solely in english language version.

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't work. It still raises <element not found error>

Comment: Could you check it again on chrome page as here: https://ibb.co/QNdbhdd

Comment: Thanks but I know you gave me the xpath of subscribe button by inspecting the YouTube webpage even I did the same but YouTube have some special encoding which doesn't let us know the correct xpath or something else related to that element. I suggest you to try it by yourself please